# Updating a game progress variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a variable named `progress` that is updated during game play (it can go up and down). It is updated every 1/10th second by using an if condition.

```
int progress = 0;
int total;

if (timedecimalpairs % 0.1m == 0) {      //Always true

    if (demandproductionrate >= 100)
        progress += 10;
    else            
        progress -= 50;

    total = progress;       
    GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 220, 277, 50, 25), total.ToString());
}
```

`timedecimalpairs` assumes the values of 0.1/0.2/0.3 sequentially, so the if condition is always true. The problem is that my `progress` variable always assumes the value 10 or -50, it doesn't sum 10+10+10 etc when the second if condition is being met. `demandproductionrate` is linked to player input during the game.

Can you help me?

Comment: You probably need to make `progress` a field of whatever class this is in rather than a variable within the current method.

Comment: You're setting progress to 0 at the top, then adding either 10 or -50. What else could progress ever be?

Comment: Got you. I was under the idea that it would initialized only one time.

Comment: want to write answer?

Comment: Please include the whole method/class to give sufficient context. As it is, we'd have to infer quite a bit in order to write an answer.

Comment: You answered my problem, it is working now thanks to your input. I just wanted to award you.

Comment: Thanks, but as a Q&A site, stack overflow needs to contain content that's complete and general enough to also help other users with similar problems. In particular, future visitors will need to see *exactly* what's wrong with the layout of original code and *exactly* how that's different in the accepted answer.

Comment: @ClaudioA, you are accidentally using the ancient "gui" system. This is deprecated and won't work.  Simply use Unity's ordinary UI.  (1. click "Add cavnas"  2. click "add slider" - you're done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime that you have your variable initialization inside of your method they are going to get initialized every time the method is called. I think in your example that you are initializing `int progress = 0;` every time the method fires. In order to correct this, remove the initialization from the method and instantiate it at the beginning of your application.